# Instantiate JavaScript object and call method at once

Tags: javascript, object, methods, instantiation

I want to instantiate a simple JavaScript object, and call its method immediately. Is is possible to do it simply, like in PHP:

```
(new Class('attr', 'attr2'))->myMethod();
```

Is there a similar syntax in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way, but with the dot notation (standard javascript):

```
(new MyObject(1)).toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just have tried it in the console because the answer is simply **yes**:

```
(new Foo()).bar();
```

but javascript is even better because you don't even need the braces:

```
new Foo().bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
 (new ClassName()).methodName();
```

you can even chain the methods If you return `this` from `methodName()`

```
(new ClassName()).methodName().secondMethod();
```

```js
var date = new Date();
alert('With later invocation '+date.toDateString())

alert('With immediate invocation '+(new Date()).toDateString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can but you have to assign the instance of that new object to a variable. You can't just call `(new MyObject(1)).myMethod()`.

From my demo:

```
(new myMethod('bob','tony')).log();
```

will produce an error:

> undefined undefined _display:28:3
>
> TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is undefined

But this will produce the right result:

```
var a = (new myMethod('bob','tony')).log(); // bob tony
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/khL634fL/)